# new id inside domain events

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm creating domain events so that they communicate between different contexts.

I thought of using the Id as the identifier of the entities, which in my case is of type long. My domain events are created within the entity itself, for example, in an AddItens function, I create an event.

That is where my problems begin as far as I could see in the .net Entity Framework I only have this id filled in after "add" (without committing the transaction). I'm using cqrs tbm and in my command handler when creating the entity and calling the AddItens function my event is created more with the id 0 because I haven't made any transactions with the bank yet.

When calling the entityframework's add/addasync function, my entity's id is filled in correctly, but my event that has already been created keeps the value 0.

What is the best practices for these cases?

I'm trying to use hilo for creating a sequence but this does not work because they create a sequence only if add/addasync function was called.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For people to be able to help, please provide a minimal reproducible example code of the issue you are facing. By default EF expects Ids that it recognizes as keys to be Identity columns (populated by DB as a central source of truth) If you want EF to ignore this and let your code manage Ids then you need to configure EF to ignore the PK values. (`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`)

Comment: Why not use `hilo` and create the event **after** calling `add/addasync`?

Comment: Welcome. I've cleaned up your question. But please take time and write well-formatted questions in the future. Spend some time on them if you want us to spend time answering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change my choice and work with UUID

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the event before the entity was stored.
Events are signals for something that has **actually** changed, if you create the event before committing the transaction nothing has changed yet.